# Display a list from an external file as "normal text"

Tags: php

I have a simple TXT file with a list of names. It's one above the other, like:

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

Is there a way to get this list and display as a normal text, with commas? Like `Name 1, Name 2, Name 3`?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a simple line of code

```
echo implode(",", file("/path/to/the/file.txt"));
```

Comment: Is there anyway of using "return" instead of echo? I am creating an wordpress shortcode, and it should be return. But, "return" does not implode. :(

Comment: `return` can be used to return any value from a function. If you want to do so, simply replace `echo` by `return`